# Abstract Algebra and Matrix Theory: Row Switching by Permutation Matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, permutations

Earlier today I came across a topic known as [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). Now, when going through elementary row operations, if I wanted to switch two rows $R_i\leftrightarrow R_j$ of a matrix $A$, I would swap the $i^{th}$ row of the identity matrix with the $j^{th}$ row which I would denote $T_{i,j}$. I then multiply $T_{i,j}$ on the left by $A$, and I continue with these transformations until I get matrix $A$ into a form that is suitable. This process takes a long time. However, with permutation matrices, I found out that you don't have to do that with row switching! Below is an illustration to see what I mean:

[image]

> $\textbf{Question:}$ How do all these transformations multiplied on the left by A become this one matrix? Or does anyone know the name of this theorem, so I can look more into it?

Comment: Switching two rows can also be achieved by multiplying by a permutation matrix. Switching two rows multiple times amounts to multiplying all those permutation matrices together, which again gives you a permutation matrix. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, how does multiplying matrices together by row switching , say $E_1E_2...E_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ equal a matrix with columns with $1's$ perfectly placed just like the picture above.

Comment: Composing permutations gives permutations, which corresponds to multiplying the permutation matrices, and permutation matrices have exactly one $1$ in each row and column.

Comment: I guess I am wanting a little more detail to how this works. For example, I am thinking let $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
3 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $\sigma=(132)=(32)(13)$ (2 cycles). So, have $\sigma_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\sigma_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, so that $\sigma=\sigma_1\cdot \sigma_2$ and have that correspond to matrices somehow, but I am just guessing.

Comment: *"have that correspond to matrices somehow"* - look up [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)

Comment: @anon I have looked at that link already, and I couldn't find anything. I appreciate your help though. Do you see how those cycles match the matrices I have below? What kind of isomorphic behavior stuff is that? I have no idea how the matrices multiply together in that way, but I did stumble upon something: $T_{3,2}T_{1,3}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I still don't understand what you're even asking. "What kind of behavior stuff" is not a real question. Yes I see why $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ match $T_{3,2}$ and $T_{1,2}$ respectively. Is that what your question is? I don't know what you mean by "how the matrices multiply together in that way," since this is just regular old matrix multiplication.

Comment: Let me be more specific. The pattern here is the following when multiplying row swapping matrices together: $T_{(3,2)}T_{(1,2)}=T_{(3,2)(1,2)}$ where $(3,2)(1,2)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\  3 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ (the mapping by the red arrows) and $T_{(3,2)(1,2)}$ represents all the matrices multiplied together which was asked in my question. Why does this pattern hold true?

Comment: Suppose $P_{\sigma}$ is the permutation matrix associated to $\sigma$. Then applying $P_{\sigma}$ to a matrix $A$ (i.e. computing $P_{\sigma}A$) has the effect of permuting the rows of $A$ according to $\sigma$. And so applying $P_{\sigma}$ followed by $P_{\tau}$ will have the effect of permuting its rows according to $\sigma$ and then $\tau$, or in other words according to $\tau\circ\sigma$. This means $P_{\tau}(P_{\sigma}A)=P_{\tau\circ\sigma}A$ identically, so $P_{\tau}P_{\sigma}=P_{\tau\circ\sigma}$.

Comment: Do you know what that theorem: $P_{\tau}P_{\sigma}=P_{\tau\circ\sigma}$ is called? I do not find that relationship obvious, and I want to prove it/learn more about it.

Comment: I just explained why it's true in my previous comment. Did you understand my explanation? The fact is too tautological to be called a theorem. It's simply a fact. The act of representing permutations by matrices is indeed a "group representation" which is called the [permutation representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_representation#Linear_permutation_representation) of the symmetric group $S_n$.

Comment: I get it. I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down the mapping shown by red arrows in the question into two cycles. Recall, the pattern for mutliplying cycles right to left to get a product of transpositions (for example $(14235)=(14)(42)(23)(35)$). For, now we will consider the first two cycles two be disjoint. In the following first sentence paragraph, we will consider the cycles to be the same, and in the last paragraph we will consider there to be one shared element between the cycles. Now, there will be many of these two cycles, but we only have to look at two of them to see what is going on. Consider the following:  $P_{(i,j)}(P_{(k,l)}A)$. First note that $P_{(k,l)}A$ becomes $A_{k\leftrightarrow l}=B$, so $k\rightarrow l$ and $l\rightarrow k$. Now, after the second matrix multiplication, we know  $P_{(i,j)}B$ becomes $B_{i\leftrightarrow j}=C$, so $i\rightarrow j$, $j\rightarrow i$, and $k\rightarrow l$ and $l\rightarrow k$ as these cycles are disjoint. All other rows in matrix $A$ that are not $i,j, k,$ or $l$ are not affected to get to $C$. Now, consider their permutations in $2$ line Cauchy notation. Consider $\sigma_1(\sigma_2(\alpha))$ when $\alpha\neq i, j, k$ or $l$. Thus, $\sigma_1(\sigma_2(\alpha))=\alpha$ which is precisely what happens to get to matrix $C$ as no rows change. Now, if $\alpha=i$, then $\alpha\rightarrow j$ to get to $C$ and similarly $\sigma_1(\sigma_2(\alpha))=j$ (cycles are disjoint). Analogously, this process holds for cases $\alpha=j$, $\alpha=k$, and $\alpha=l$. Multiplying by another matrix on the left, we know this pattern continues recursively as our multiplied matrices then acts like $A$ did in the beginning.

Now, if the cycles are the same, nothing happens to the matrix $C$, and similarly nothing happens to the cycles (i.e. $\forall \alpha, \sigma_1(\sigma_2(\alpha))=\alpha$). Now, the only other case is for the cycles to share one element. So, simply define $i=k$. Thus, $B$ has $i\rightarrow l$ and $l\rightarrow i$. Then, $C$ has $i\rightarrow j$ (in other words $l$ went to $j$ altogether) and $j\rightarrow i$ (so $j$ went to  $i$, and $i$ went to $l$ altogether). No other rows were switched in this process. Now, for the cycles, we want to show $l$ goes to $j$, $j$ goes to  $i$, and $i$ goes to $l$.

Well, define $\beta$ to be the product of both cycles,  $(i,j)$ and $(k,l)$ respectively when $i=k$. Well, $\beta(l)$ went to k and then to $j$, so $\beta(l)=j$ (showed $l$ went to $j$ all together). Now, $\beta(k)$ went to $l$ and stayed put, so $\beta(k)=l$; in addition, $\beta(i)$ went to $l$ and stayed put, so $\beta(i)=l$. Hence, we showed with this last sentence that $i$ went to $l$ all together (showed $i$ went to $l$ all together). Lastly, $\beta(j)$ stayed put and then went to i, so $\beta(j)=i$ (showed $j$ went to $i$ all together). This pattern continues recursively as our multiplied matrices acts like $A$ in the beginning.